# Rails select register from the previous day

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to get the model instances with one day of history. I'm using postgreSQL.

What i want is likeness this:

```
element = Element.find(:first , :conditions => ["name LIKE ? AND created_at < ---ONE_DAY_CONDITION---)
```

What is the best way to solve it using a SQL query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `1.day.ago`?

```
element = Element.find(:first, 
    :conditions => ["name LIKE ? AND created_at > ?", whatever, 1.day.ago])
```